# Check player response on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a language learning game.

The player will be asked to type in a sentence... as they go, I want to give them immediate feedback to tell them they're on the right track (similar to how a password will indicate on the fly if your pw is strong enough).

To do this, I will use jQuery, and the output will tell them "good" as they type it in. If they miss a letter, it will say something like "oops." When the user has typed in the length of the given sentence, jQuery will automatically know this and say something like "great job."

```
Type in response: <input type="text" onkeyup="playerResponse(this.value)" name="input" value="" /> 
<br /><span id="responseVerify"></span><br />
```

How would the jQuery look? I know how to use a $.get method to send input to the server side and process with PHP, but not how to do so with javascript. I'm guessing I would use a javascript substring to analyze the input as they type?

Would it be something like this?

```
function playerResponse(input) {
    log("test");
    var string = "Wo Shi Dan";
    if (input == string.substring()) {
        log("great");
    }
}
```

But the JS substring wants me to specify how much to truncate. In PHP, I was using `if (strtolower($input)==strtolower(substr($row['imgname'],0,strlen($input))))` as they typed something in to compare dynamically per letter to the `$row['imgname']`

Thanks!

---

EDIT: I wanted to return a response to the player in real time. I'd like to do something similar to this... And I want to highlight the character in red if they mistyped.

```
function playerResponse(input) {
    var string = "Wo Shi Dan";
    if (input == string.substring()) {
        $("#responseVerify").html("Great job");
    }
    else {
        $("#responseVerify").html("Keep going...");
    }
}
```

Comment: your code looks ok. Have you tested it?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini well the log works, but it doesn't work with the substring as they're typing. Also, I want to return a response in real time to the user as they're typing. See edit

Comment: check the documentation for `string.substring`

Answer (score 0):

```
function playerResponse(value) {
    $.ajax({
       type:'GET', 
       url: 'check_valid.php', 
       data: $.param({text: value})
    }).done(function(response){
        //update the result as good or oops
    });;
}
```

You php code has to handle the text input and return the validation

Comment: Is this relying on `check_valid.php` for verification? I wanted to stay away from verifying on the server side

Comment: However if the connection is something slow, this can lead to very bad results (such as the response of a previous keystroke being processed later)

Comment: @Growler In that case, do you have all the valid words in your client side?

Comment: @arun15thmay yes I will have these on the client side.

Comment: @Growler how about the following
`function playerResponse(value)
{
var arr= ['One', 'two', 'three']
for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++)
{
  if(arr[i].indexOf(value) != -1)
  {
   //match found
  }
  else 
  {
    //no match found
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could put your strings in an array and use `$.inArray` function. Otherwise you could use the `str.contains` function, but I think you don't want all possible substrings, but only the words separated by spaces.